# How do I persist my mouse's pointer speed?

Tags: windows, mouse

Every time I reboot, I need to to go the Control Panel → *Mouse Properties* → *Pointer Options* and crank up the pointer speed. Is there a way to persist this setting?

I've had the same problem with Windows Vista and Windows 7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could throw a batch file in your startup folder:

```
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Mouse" /v MouseSensitivity /t REG_SZ /d 20 /f
```

Just change the sensitivity as desired. 1 (lowest) - 20 (highest). Save as `mouse.bat` for example, then put it in the startup folder in your start menu.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Windows 7. The only thing that seems to work is by using the Mouse section of the control panel.

Comment: @Pat you have to run it as administrator.

Comment: I have it in my startup folder, so it runs under my (admin) user on login. When I run it by right-clicking and selected 'run as administrator', it still doesn't work.

Comment: @JohnT the value in regedit gets changed here, but there is no effect on the mouse speed. Do i have to commit it somehow or something similar maybe?

Comment: @JohnT Same problem as Jo Smo. Registry key gets changed, mouse speed doesn't update.